# how to efficiently remove null from the list?

Tags: java

In a scenario where a map of coreValues contains:
Value 1 -> List("1", "2", null, "3")
I want to filter out null values from the list, i have
below solution:

```
 boolean hasCoreValues = false;
 Optional<Map<String,List<String>> coreValues = buildCoreValuesMap(core); 
 hasCoreValues = corevalues.map(cv -> {
    final List<String> values = cv.getOrDefault(value, Immutable.of())
    values.removeAll(singletonList(null));
    return !values.isEmpty();
 }).orElse(false);



public Optional<Map<String, List<String>>> buildCoreValuesMap(String core) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(context.selectFrom(DataStorage)
                .where(DataStorage.CORE.in(core))
                .fetchGroups(DataStorage.CORE,
                        DataStorage.VALUES));
    }
```

is there a better way to do it without going thru the list again to remove the null?

Comment: values.removeAll(singletonList(null)) i am using the method to remove null, its not a duplicate question. My question is to how to remove null without iterating twice.

Comment: can you show the code of this method `buildCoreValuesMap` ?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to remove all `null` in `List<String>` from `coreValues`, then just iterate `Map` and remove all `null` values from list using `removeIf`

```
coreValues.forEach((k,v)-> v.removeIf(Objects::isNull));
```

Comment: Of course, if you wrote `buildCoreValuesMap()` you might employ a filter to keep them out in the first place.

Comment: can i avoid iterating map twice?

Comment: can you show the first place where you are iterating map ? @MikasaAckerman

Comment: Well, I can't provide an answer now because the question  has been marked as a duplicate.  But Deadpool could tag on an edit and probably show you how to do it.

Comment: In order to do that OP needs to show the code of `buildCoreValuesMap` @WJS

Comment: @Deadpool  Yes I know.  But you could probably gen up a simple example which he might be able to adapt.

Comment: sorry it is not really clear to me, until and unless he shows the code, because i don't know the internal logic. But you are always welcome to edit my answer with valuable information @WJS

Comment: updated the question

Comment: actually i never used this library  @MikasaAckerman which library is this ?

Comment: jooq library is being used here